# Google Map addCircle above GroundOverlayOptions

Tags: android, google-maps

I am drawing image on Google Map using

```
map.GroundOverlayOptions()
```

Now I am trying to draw circle on this image. I am using

```
map.addCircle()
```

But the circle is being drawn under the image. I have also tried to draw circle using Post() of Handler so that it is added later, but it still draws under the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `zIndex()` method of [Circle](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Circle) and [GroundOverlay](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/GroundOverlay) objects:

> The order of overlays with the same zIndex value is arbitrary. This is
>   optional and the default zIndex is 0.

Something like that:

```
GroundOverlayOptions overlay = new GroundOverlayOptions()
        .image(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(mBitmap))
        .transparency(0f)
        .zIndex(1f)
        .positionFromBounds(borders);

mGoogleMap.addGroundOverlay(overlay);

mGoogleMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
        .center(new LatLng(borders.getCenter().latitude, borders.getCenter().longitude))
        .radius(100000)
        .strokeColor(Color.RED)
        .zIndex(2f)
        .fillColor(Color.BLUE));
```